# Can't find EF Wizard in VS2012, Do I need to resinstall something?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I'm using VS2012, and want to create a model first EF model.  If I pick Add/Class then pick the Data option I don't see any of the EF tools there.  Problem is that I'm using EF 5.0 and I have no idea how to get the EDMX wizard stuff back into VS... Is this a EF power tool?  Or is it a DBContext generator thing I'm missing?

I already uninstalled EF 6.0 and installed EF 5.0 through NuGet, but still can't see the EDMX template creator wizard when trying to add a class....

Any help is appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok somehow I had uninstalled the EF tooling, after downloading and installing this:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762

Everything came back...